# Finding the position of a zero without doing explicit calculations

Tags: frequency-response, pole-zeroplot

I have the following circuit:

[image]

It is a fully-differential amplifier. Since the circuit is symmetrical with respect to the vertical axis, only the right portion (for example) can be studied to find vout-; the voltage vout+ is simply 180° phase shifted.

I was able to find an expression for the dc (low-frequency) gain which perfecly matches with simulations performed with Cadence Virtuoso. However, I have difficulties in analyzing the frequency response. I would expect a dominant pole at the output node due to the (single-ended) output resistance and output capacitance. But looking at the differential voltage gain:

[image]

you can see that there is also a zero at frequency 1.8GHz. How can I find it? One way would be to apply KCL and KVL to the circuit, but I think it would be very complex with all these transistors! Is there a more intuitive way to find it, or at least can you give me some hints to analitycally find it? This circuit somehow remembers to me a differential pair with active load. Razavi shows in his book that actually a zero is present in such a circuit, also justifying it as a consequence of the presence of two parallel paths between the input and the output. In my circuit it seems to be the same case: considering only half circuit, transistors M6-M7-M5-M4-M3 create one path, whereas transistors M1-M2 create another parallel path, thus intuitively justifying the presence of a zero.

Comment: At a 90 ps time constant, I'd be looking at Ohmic gate resistance and Cgs, perhaps. I assume these are monolithic. Which model? What are the parameters? I know very little about monolithic design. So I'm just curious, is all. But the parameters might be around the right range and arranged for a zero, seems to me. But I'm honestly just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the circuit you have presented but I would need to convert it to a linear small-signal schematic before being able to infer anything. One way to check if a zero is present in a linear circuit is to apply the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs I describe in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) on the subject. The technique is quite simple to determine whether one of the energy-storing element  a \$L\$ or a \$C\$ - contributes a zero to the transfer function: you place the considered element in its high-frequency state - a short circuit for a capacitor or an open circuit for an inductor - and see if the *stimulus* produces a *response* at the output port. It works for passive and active elements. This technique was described by Ali Ajimiri in his paper *[General Time- and Transfer-Constant Circuit Analysis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/216139384.pdf)* and I have successfully applied the technique at numerous occasions. Below are a few simple examples where I highlight the presence of a zero or not:

[image]

The idea here is to reuse the time constant(s) already determined for the pole(s) and determine the zero position that way. An alternate option is to perform a NDI and check the condition in the circuit which explains why the response can be a *null* at the zero frequency.